# Is using rounded and cornered icons in the same menu a bad practice?

Tags: interface, users

Title says it all. I don't know what to do. I am neither able to find the right icon pack, nor I am able to design them myself. I've been looking for icons since the morning.
Is that a bad practice for UI design?

---

[image] [image]

---

Each icon has a text which explains what that icon does when it is clicked.

Comment: You want to use two different icon types in the same menu navigation ? Is that your question

Comment: Yes, I do. Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Proximity implies relation, make sure the elements look related. If not, the meaning could be confusing, appear amateurish or like a mistake. An illustration in a banner won't have the same purpose as a 14px icon in a menu.

It seems the '317Jfez.png' icons are tough to read, due to low contrast and colors might not work well for anyone with colorblindness.

A couple of nice sets are http://glyphicons.com/ (by way of Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/components/ ) and http://fontawesome.io/ ...there are a slew of others or you can make your own.

The nice thing about icon fonts is that you can style them using CSS and are resolution independent. This is great because the icons will be consistent with typographic styles, hopefully aiding legibility. Most browsers support webfonts.

I am making alot of assumptions without a better appreciation of how you will use the icons. Hope this was somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I really liked fontawesome's icon set and it is very customizable, but they are so simple. Not in a bad way, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, though it depends on the icon set. Your icon set can include both round and square icons, but the first set is 3/5 round and 2/5 standard icons, while the second set is 5/5 icons (with one that just happens to be a perfectly round icon). Therefore, your second set looks more like a proper set.

However, there are no specific rules that state you can't use both rounded and cornered icons. The real challenge here is making sure all of the icons are the same relative size. Round icons use the least space possible (those corners are completely lost) while cornered icons are much more space-efficient. In your case, there are more difficulties with the color variation and overall differences, but it looks like you're using these solely as examples.